# get serial number in reverse order in vue js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

below is the code for displaying serial number while iterating list.
now i cant sort the list due to some reasons and the list will be as it is.
but i want serial number to be printed in reverse order. If size of array is 5 i need 5 4 3 2 1.

```
<table class="table" border=1 width="650" style="word-wrap:break-word">
         <tr>
          <td colspan="6" class="heading">
            <b>Corrigendum Document Details</b>
          </td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
                <th align="center" style="width:7.5%">Corr.No.</th>
                <th align="center">Corrigendum Title</th>
                <th align="center">Corrigendum Description</th>
                <th align="center">Published Date</th>
                <th align="center">Document Name</th>
                <th align="center">Doc Size(in KB)</th>
              </tr>
              <tr v-for="(corrworkdoc,index) in corrWorkItemDocumentsAndCorrDetailList" i = index>
                <td>{{index+1}}</td>
                <td>{{corrworkdoc.corrigendumTitle}}</td>
                <td>{{corrworkdoc.corrigendumDescription}}</td>
                <td>{{corrworkdoc.publishedDate}}</td>
                <td><a href="#" v-on:click="doDownload(corrworkdoc.fileName)" title="Download" style="color:blue;">{{corrworkdoc.fileName}}</a></td>
                <td>{{corrworkdoc.docSize}}</td>
              </tr>
    </table>
```

how to display the serial number in reverse order.

Comment: You just wanted the index or even the contents?

Comment: Can't you create a copy of main array and reverse it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a computed property and reverse the array or directly in the template as Saeed.At example. Also set the correct index value.

```
computed: {
   reverseDetailedList() {
      return this.corrWorkItemDocumentsAndCorrDetailList.slice().reverse();
   }
```

And in the template:

```
<tr v-for="(corrworkdoc,index) in reverseDetailedList" :key="index">
   <td>{{ reverseDetailList.length - index }}</td>
   <td>{{ corrworkdoc.corrigendumTitle}}</td>
```

Comment: (corrWorkItemDocumentsAndCorrDetailList.length) - index worked. Nice idea. With out reversing the original list now we can reverse serial number. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<tr v-for="(corrworkdoc,index) in corrWorkItemDocumentsAndCorrDetailList.reverse()" i = index>
            <td>{{index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{corrworkdoc.corrigendumTitle}}</td>
            <td>{{corrworkdoc.corrigendumDescription}}</td>
            <td>{{corrworkdoc.publishedDate}}</td>
            <td><a href="#" v-on:click="doDownload(corrworkdoc.fileName)" title="Download" style="color:blue;">{{corrworkdoc.fileName}}</a></td>
            <td>{{corrworkdoc.docSize}}</td>
          </tr>
```

Comment: but the list order should not be changed only serial number but be printed in reverse order. I cant reverse the list